# Do stackoverflow users get job offers?

Tags: discussion, users, jobs

I know there's no private messaging system, but I'm wondering if users with high reps get contacted often to be offered jobs / projects.

Comment: I've personally received three in the year or two I've been on Stack Overflow, and my reputation isn't particularly high.

Comment: I use [Careers](http://s.tk/careers) and got offers and was eventually hired.  I'm told my rep and quality of answers on Stack Overflow was a big factor.

Comment: I've had offers through careers, including ones that represent a pretty good match between my skills and their needs.

Comment: I've received offers through Careers, and my current job was something I actively found on Careers (they didn't find me, I found them).  But that's all.  Maybe I should add some contact info to my profile...

Comment: I've received maybe 10-15 over the years. About 5 of which were serious long-term employment offers

Comment: @Pekka: And not one of them in the states huh, or bay area?

Comment: @Jeff actually, there were! Promising ones as well. But none worked out. Immigration paperwork is tough, especially when trying to get to the Bay Area :( (I need to update that profile though, I'm not acutely looking right now, studying will get me over to the US for a year, which is a great way to dip my toes first.)

Comment: I have, and they have cited my rep, or have done pre-interview research and found my SO profile.

Comment: See also [Will high reputation in Stack Overflow help to get a good job?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/20407/will-high-reputation-in-stack-overflow-help-to-get-a-good-job)

Comment: I've never gotten one, but I'm not on Careers. I assume they'd all go through there, rather than a comment on one of my answers. Alternatively, maybe no one likes me or thinks I know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no definitive answer to your question.

There are two ways you might end up with jobs / projects requests in Stack Overflow. Note the use of *Might*.

1. Through [Careers](http://s.tk/careers).
2. If your profile gives some kind of information on how to contact you then, yes. This usually happens when you have been particularly very helpful to a particular user and the user realizes that he or she could hire you to get something done. There are times when you get projects requests from unknown users as well. **High Reps** do play a part but not much. Else everyone with high reps would start getting offers. ;)

In my 7 years of posting answers in 4 different forums, I have had my good share of Project Requests. In fact I still get at least 1 in a month. I don't recollect a single instance (*except which came from unknown users or through my blog*) where my reps played a part. Why, I remember getting an offer when I had just 2k in Stack Overflow!