# Is it allowed to announce a freelance project here?

Tags: discussion, support

I'm needing help with my website and I cannot fix it.
I guess that the solution is not so simple, so I wouldn't receive a good answer.

So can I post a question offering money to who fix it?

Comment: No, you can't. But you can visit [careers.stackoverflow.com](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) and hire someone.

Comment: Absolutely not!

Comment: I'm not sure Careers here is a good match - isn't that for significant/permanent sources of employment? I'd do a web search for "website hire freelancer", adding in your country and/or technology to narrow down your results.

Comment: I wonder why such a question would be downvoted? The user asked if he may do something rather than just doing, and I also don't remember of the topic being described in FAQ. A short answer "no" would be sufficient - IMO... P.S. no, I'm not related to the asker in any way.

Comment: @AlexShesterov Because questions asked here are up/downvoted differently than other sites. A downvote here means I disagree. Doesn't make a whole lot of sense, but that's the way it is.

Comment: @MichaelTodd: oh, ok... Thanks for clarification!

Comment: [Interesting read](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122725/do-stackoverflow-users-get-job-offers)

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176671/172661

Answer (score 8):

Good Question. The answer is no, but you can visit [careers.stackoverflow.com](http://careers.stackoverflow.com) and hire somebody.

If you can't afford that, you can browse the profiles of people that are good in the tags relevant to your website and see whether or not they have contact information in their profile. Most do not, but some do.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is no. If this is your requirement, you should try oDesk or matchist, and hire a freelance developer.

Then when there comes a point that you have doubt about some of the code or design done by your contractor, go ask here in SO.